# sumar 2 columnas con diferente ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo la siguiente consulta en sql pero lo que pasa es que me devuelve 2 filas y yo solo quiero 1 fila quisiera que la columna FILMINA se sume y PLIEGO tambien
como podría hacer eso?

```
SELECT I.StockNominal,
       I.StockNominal2,
       CASE M.IdTipoMov
            WHEN 4 THEN SUM(M.CantidaConforme) + I.StockNominal
            WHEN 5 THEN -SUM(M.CantidaConforme)
       END AS Pliego,
       CASE M.IdTipoMov
            WHEN 4 THEN —I.StockNominal2 + SUM(M.CantidadConfLamina)
            WHEN 5 THEN -SUM(M.CantidadConfLamina)
       END AS Filmina
FROM Inventario I
     LEFT JOIN MovimientoMaterial M ON I.FechaInventario = M.FechaHoraReg
WHERE I.FechaInventario = '2022-02-10'
GROUP BY M.CantidaConforme,
         I.StockNominal,
         I.StockNominal2,
         M.IdTipoMov;
```

**las flechas señalan que tengo 2 registros que quiero sumar**

[image: las flechas señalan que tengo 2 re]

Comment: Hola @Marcos cuando los saco me sale un error diciendo que se necesita de esos campos

Comment: @Marcos La columna 'MovimientoMaterial.IdTipoMov' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente no termino de entender tu consulta.

Así mismo, una solución para obtener el resultado que necesitas es utilizar los datos devuelto por consulta actual como fuente de datos de otra consulta que los modele a tu gusto.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    T.StockNominal,
    T.StockNominal2,
    SUM(T.Pliego) AS Pliego,
    SUM(T.Filmina) AS Filmina
FROM (
    SELECT I.StockNominal,
           I.StockNominal2,
           CASE M.IdTipoMov
                WHEN 4 THEN SUM(M.CantidaConforme) + I.StockNominal
                WHEN 5 THEN -SUM(M.CantidaConforme)
           END AS Pliego,
           CASE M.IdTipoMov
                WHEN 4 THEN —I.StockNominal2 + SUM(M.CantidadConfLamina)
                WHEN 5 THEN -SUM(M.CantidadConfLamina)
           END AS Filmina
    FROM Inventario I
         LEFT JOIN MovimientoMaterial M ON I.FechaInventario = M.FechaHoraReg
    WHERE I.FechaInventario = '2022-02-10'
    GROUP BY M.CantidaConforme,
             I.StockNominal,
             I.StockNominal2,
             M.IdTipoMov
) AS T
GROUP BY T.StockNominal, T.StockNominal2;
```

Comment: Funciono! gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo disculpa, este mensaje debería ser un comentario pero no tengo la puntuación suficiente. Si el resultado es el que muestras, ¿Puede ser que M.CantidaConforme o M.IdTipoMov sea distinto?, es necesario agrupar por este campo distinto?

Comment: Hola cuando quito el campo IdTipoMov o CantidadCoonforme me sale el siguiente error "La columna 'MovimientoMaterial.IdTipoMov' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY"